# Acessing current object from nested function

Tags: jquery, tinymce, mcimagemanager

How do I pass $(this) object to the function inside click event.

```
$('#mainwrap img').click(function(){      
    mcImageManager.browse({
        oninsert : function(o) {
            src= o.focusedFile.url;
            $(this).attr("src", src );
        }
    });
});
```

Any suggestion will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to pass $('#mainwrap img') inside `oninsert` function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` is a special variable - each time a function is entered it takes on a new value.

In this case to make the outer function's `this` available in the inner function, you can bind a new variable to it outside of the nested function:

```
$('#mainwrap img').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);      // new variable here 
    mcImageManager.browse({
        oninsert : function(o) {
            src= o.focusedFile.url;
            $this.attr("src", src );  // referenced here
        }
    });
});
```